# How to position a nested div in the absolute upper left hand corner of the viewport, regardless of its ancestors

Tags: html, css

How do I position a div in the upper left hand corner of the viewport using CSS only?

I know the following doesn't work, since it will not put the element in the top left corner if ancestors of the element have certain css properties (such as background blurs):

```
.topleft {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

I cannot control the ancestors of this element, so I am unable to use any solution that requires controlling or knowing the margins of elements higher in the DOM tree. Javascript is also not allowed.

Here is an example showing how the styling of ancestor elements can break the positioning:

```css
body div.main-container {
  background-color: green;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  max-width: 300px;
  margin:auto;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.fake-root {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<body class="no-scroll">
  <div class="main-container grid-y grid-margin-y grid-container">
    <div class="cell auto main">
      <main role="main">
        <app>
          <div class="fake-root">
            Hello world<br />
            Not top left
          </div>
        </app>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? It *should* regardless of any margin or padding of any ancestors. https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/QWPyZEE

Comment: Here is a screenshot demonstrating that the element is not always positioned in the upper left hand corner: https://i.imgur.com/PFzktYP.png

Comment: You're gonna have to demo that because I can't get that effect even without a CSS reset (see the Codepen)

Comment: _I know the following doesn't work, since it will not put the element in the top left corner if ancestors of the element have margins and padding_ - This is totally wrong [unless any ancestor has `transform`, `perspective`, or `filter` property set to something other than `none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#examples) because fixed positioned element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout.

Comment: `position: fixed` and `absolute` are always positioned relative to a screen ... unless one of the parent elements in the DOM is not `static`

Comment: if any ancestors have `transform`, `perspective`, or `filter` property set to something other than `none` and you can't control them, nether adding JS, most likely you'd never achieve the desired result unless the created space is known and always the same, thus, you can adjust `top` and `left` accordingly with negative values equals the margin/padding created.

Comment: Here's the Codepen that reproduces it... note that there is no `transform`, `perspective` or `filter` property: https://codepen.io/Jeremy-Salwen/pen/RwOreKm

Comment: @Anonymous I'm sorry to tell that's not true, [check this](https://jsfiddle.net/8jebwtg7/) and [read more on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: It looks like the `backdrop-filter: blur(10px);` is required for this behavior.... not sure why...

Comment: so now it's clear that the issue is coming from that `backdrop-filter`, remove it and you'll get what you're looking for.

Comment: “ t looks like the backdrop-filter: blur(10px); is required for this behaviour… not sure why” - reading up about containing block may help you see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block#identifying_the_containing_block

Comment: The [mre] *must* be included in the question itself, not linked offsite.

Comment: Unfortunately your claim that "The minimal reproducible example *must* be included in the question itself, not linked offsite." is simply incorrect.  To quote the document you linked: "When asking a debugging question, *people will be better able to provide help* if you provide code as text in your question that prospective answerers can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem."  (emphasis mine).  The MWE is not necessary to understand the question nor answer it, its existence merely refutes the claim that the question is not reproducible.

Answer (score -1):

You can use grid property for controlling elements position.

```css
* {
  margin:0; /* reset all margins beginning of the css file */
}
body {
    display: grid;
    place-items: start;
}
.top-left {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-left"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not answer the question about positioning at the top left corner regardless of the ancestor elements.